# How bind server side function result on aspx page markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

Is there possible something like that?

```
<a id="username" href="http://www.prepp.me/profile/<%: GetUserGUID()  %>"><%: Context.User.Identity.Name %></a>
```

With such server side code:

```
public string GetUserGUID()
        {
            PREPP2Entities db = new PREPP2Entities();
            var uid = (from a in db.Users where a.Login.Contains(Context.User.Identity.Name) select a.UserGUID).First();
            return uid;
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks okay to me. Any problem with it?

Comment: Yes. CS0103: The name 'GetUserGUID' does not exist in the current context. Is this syntax <%: %> available for Models only?

Comment: Where is your method defined?

Comment: and where is your html?

Comment: Site.master of course.

Comment: `<%:` just HTML encodes the output of the function. So that is not the source of your problem. Will take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

C# Function:

```
 public string GetText()
    {
     //your functionality
    }
```

Aspx Page Code:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%=GetText()%>'></asp:Label>
```